# Scotty api with mysql simple in haskell

Tags: mysql, haskell, scotty

I am following [this](http://taylor.fausak.me/2014/10/21/building-a-json-rest-api-in-haskell/) tutorial which uses scotty with persistent to create a simple API .

However, I am trying to create a simple api with scotty and mysql simple library.

Now I am stuck at one point in code .

In the below code I am not able to convert **getUser** function to type **"ActionT Error ConfigM"** because of which my code is failing.

***Can anyone help me with understanding how I can convert getUser function to achieve needed type signature?***

**Code**

```
type Error = Text
type Action = ActionT Error ConfigM ()

config :: Config
config = Config
    { environment = Development 
     ,db1Conn = connect connectionInfo
    }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  runApplication config

runApplication :: Config -> IO ()
runApplication c = do
  o <- getOptions (environment c)
  let r m = runReaderT (runConfigM m) c
  scottyOptsT o r application

application :: ScottyT Error ConfigM ()
application = do
  e <- lift (asks environment)
  get "/user" getTasksA

getTasksA :: Action
getTasksA = do
    u <- getUser
    json u 

getUser :: IO User
getUser = do
  e <- asks environment
  conn <- db1Conn config 
  [user]<- query_ conn "select login as userId, email as userEmail from member limit 1"
  return user
```

**Error**

```
• Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘ActionT Error ConfigM’
      Expected type: ActionT Error ConfigM User
        Actual type: IO User
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: u <- getUser
      In the expression:
        do { u <- getUser;
             json u }
      In an equation for ‘getTasksA’:
          getTasksA
            = do { u <- getUser;
                   json u }
```

Comment: If you drop the signature of `IO User`, it will probably work.

Comment: Tried that. Got following error Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘ActionT Error ConfigM’
      Expected type: ActionT Error ConfigM a0
        Actual type: IO a0

Answer (score 2):

You left out plenty of code (imports and pragmas and the definitions of `User`, please include that next time - see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

But now to your question:

I would change the `Action` type to the following

```
type Action a = ActionT Error ConfigM a
```

then `getTasksA` has the following type signature

```
getTasksA :: Action ()
getTasksA = do
    u <- getUser
    json u
```

(alternatively you can write this as `getTasksA = getUser >>= json`)

and `getUser`

```
getUser :: Action User
getUser = do
  e <- asks environment
  conn <- db1Conn config 
  [user] <- liftIO $ query_ conn "select login as userId, ..."
  return user
```

### A few remarks

- `[user] <- liftIO $ query ..` is a bad idea - if no user is found this crashes your application - try to write total functions and pattern matches. Better return a `Maybe User`.

  ```
  getUser :: Action (Maybe User)
  getUser = do
    e <- asks environment
    conn <- db1Conn config 
    fmap listToMaybe . liftIO $ query_ conn "select login as userId, ..."
  ```
- if you can wrap your head around it, rather use `persistent` than writing your SQL queries by hand - this is quite error prone, especially when refactoring, just imagine renaming `userId` to `userID`.
- you `ask` several times for the `environment` but then don't use it. Compile with `-Wall` or even `-Werror` to get a warning or even elevate warnings to compile errors (which is a good idea for production settings.

Comment: Also, I actually wanted to use Persistent library but then Persistent creates my data type dynamically . Like User data type in this case . And then I will have to import that file everywhere in my code where I want to use User data type , which will create dependency of Persistent in my entire code base . Hence, I am not using it .